# Type does not conform to protocol 'AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate'

Tags: swift, macos, audio, compiler-errors

I am trying to use AVCaptureMovieFileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL to record audio to a file, and the syntax for the function asks for a variable of type "AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate."  All of the help I've seen from this site says that you need to make a class an extension of AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate, and NSObject.

Problem is, I always get the error: **Type 'AVRecordDevices' does not conform to protocol 'AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate'**

How do I fix it?

[image: Class with error]

P.S. I am developing for OS X if that means anything in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that you don't have the proper methods implemented in your view controller:

By taking a closer look at apple´s docs you'll see that is mandatory to have at least this:

```
  func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!)
    {
    }
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate_Protocol/

Comment: Thank you!  I did not notice that function in the documentation!

Answer (score 6):

**Updated answer for Swift 4.0:**

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturefileoutputrecordingdelegate).

```
import AVFoundation

extension ViewController: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput,
                    didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL,
                    from connections: [AVCaptureConnection],
                    error: Error?) {
        // Handle output
    }
}
```

**Original answer for Swift 3.0:**

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, 
    didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, 
    fromConnections connections: [Any]!, 
    error: Error!) { }
```